# How to select only time without attaching a date?

Tags: 8, datetime

Is there a field in Drupal 8 that lets you select a time without actually selecting a date? Or should you just use datetime?

Comment: No.  I'll try to write up a comprehensive answer tonight.

Comment: You can use https://www.drupal.org/project/time_field module.

Answer (score 2):

You can use datetime element and disable date widget:

```
$widget['time_container']['time'] = [
  '#type' => 'datetime',
  '#title' => $this->t('Time'),
  '#size' => 20,
  '#date_date_element' => 'none', // hide date element 
  '#date_time_element' => 'time', // you can use text element here as well 
  '#date_time_format' => 'H:i'
];
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, i got error on validation because Drupal validateDatetime are looking for  $date = $input['object']; and in your case object is empty.

Comment: you can use '#validated' => true to avoid issue in validation

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to select time for, you may want to try [HMS field](https://www.drupal.org/project/hms_field).

> The field stores values as integer. Both input and output can be
>   formatted as Hours, Minutes and/or Seconds. Alter functions provide a
>   way for developers to add their own format.

Please note that this is a great field for "time durations," but not so good if you are trying to capture a time of day with PM/AM.

[Timefield](https://www.drupal.org/project/timefield) was a good option for capturing just time of the day, BUT it has not been ported to Drupal 8.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use https://www.drupal.org/project/time_field module. Easy and perfect fit.