# Why does changing date portion of a datetime string on node presave subtract an hour from the time portion?

Tags: 8, datetime

I have two *datetime* fields, one only accepts date input and the other is only accepting time input (via the technique where you set the `['#date_date_element'] = 'none'` as described in [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/245887/48114)). In `hook_node_presave` the date field shows a value like `2018-10-11` and the time field shows a value like `2018-10-11T23:36:01-0400`. I'm altering the latter string - I'm changing just the date portion to match the value from my date only field. The problem I'm running into is that, for some reason, every time I save the node the time field goes back an hour, e.g. 10:00:00 to 09:00:00 to 08:00:00. This does not happen when I comment out my code in presave AND it also does not happen on my local machine, only on the remote development environment.

```
function MYMODULE_node_presave($node) {
  $time = $node->field_time->value;
  $node->field_time->value = $node->field_date->value . substr($time, strpos($time, 'T'));
}
```

What can be causing this behavior?

(FYI: I'm abandoning this approach and I'm going to use the [time_field module](https://www.drupal.org/project/time_field))

Comment: Did you check the time zone set in the remote server `timedatectl | grep “Time zone”`?

Comment: `Time zone: Etc/UTC (UTC, +0000)`. Drupal is set to `America/New_York`

Comment: Try to set drupal timezone to `america/New_York`   `date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');`  and test if the issue comes from time zone .

Comment: Can you confirm the field types and config of `field_time` and `field_date`?  Storage of datetime fields is UTC w/o an offset string.  I am also a little confused that you are saying that `field_date` is date-only but showing '2018-10-11T23:36:01-0400' since if it should really just be a Y-m-d string as the value, and if you are working with the date object, the time portion should be noon UTC.

Comment: Yes, you're right about the date field's value, sorry I had that wrong in the description. The fields are both `datetime` fields.